# Unable to build JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, build, jar, ant

I just install `openJDK 8` *(1.8.0_191)* and realized that it does not include **JavaFX**, so I searched on some SO posts and found `openJFX`.

After installing it, everything worked well. I was able to create and run my JavaFX applications. 
The problem is that when I try to build my JavaFX app, it throws some crazy Exceptions. 
The build completes successfully if it is not a JavaFX app. Here is a screenshot of part of the stack trace.
[image]

I'm using `Netbeans 8.2` as my IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the files tab of your project you need to find the project.properties file. There you should search for **java.fx.deploy.includeDT=TRUE**, set this value to False.

See this: http://hongouru.blogspot.com/2015/09/solved-error-building-new-project-using.html